# Kamailio xhttp module (Websocket) header on SIP logic

Tags: http, nginx, websocket, http-headers, kamailio

I have a `Kamailio` behind a `nginx` for websockets secure. `nginx` setup some headers like `X-Forwarded-For` and I want to handle this values on main routing logic.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the header should be available inside **event_route** for **xhttp** module via **$hdr(X-Forwarded-For)**.

Comment: I'm asking how to pass this values to main route. There are a way to do?

Comment: Hi @miconda, I have a pair of tools to do this, `$shv` and `$sht` variable types. I can get header value from `event_route[xttp:request]` when uprade to WS, and make it available in `request_route` thru $conid.

Comment: In request_route you get the SIP messages sent over the websocket, not the http requests. So you need to store the HTTP header with operations inside event route, and you pointed, using a hash table with connection id is a good solution. The $shv(...) is a single value variable and its name is static, it doesn't work if you have more than one websocket connection. Use $sht(...).